# Error opening Iris.tab file in Orange load data widget

Tags: orange

[image]

I am attempting to load in the Iris.tab data set into the Orange load data widget. However, when I do this, I get the following error message (shown above).

This keeps popping up when I start up Orange Data Mining and try to load the iris.tab data file. It used to work before, but now it is showing this error.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and what might be causing this error?

Comment: It seems your `iris.tab` file is broken. Could you please upload this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an [error](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1997) in Orange 3.3.11, and fixed in release 3.3.12. Update to the newest release to get rid of the error.

Comment: @Ethan Just grab the current .dmg installer for macOS from http://orange.biolab.si/download/